# Android Studio referencing issues between two versions

Tags: java, android, android-studio, data-conversion

I'm trying to follow this online class on making a Java App and the video I'm learning from is using a very outdated version of Android Studio compared to what is available. I tried using the older module from the archives but I'm getting errors, so I'm using the new one but there's a bunch of different issues. Like the one im using is trying to make it simple but its making it worst for instance using semi colons are redundant.

I noticed my main is not public but when I try its greyed out calling it redundant, other than that its line 18 that starts my errors I think, when I try to go letter for letter from the video its just red and wrong starting from line 17. Also Looks like variables and declarations are a little off.

Side By Side Left is demo, Right is mine:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue is not with the android studio the issue is your left side image code is in JAVA language and what you are doing (Right side code) it's in KOTLIN language. [image: Choose language while creating project].

You need to have language as JAVA to do the same program or better find a tutorial which gives you same thing in KOTLIN as it's far better than JAVA.

Comment: *face palm* I'll take another whack at it. Its so similar